# Pan and zoom functionality in uiaxes in matlab appdesigner

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

Is there any workaround to add pan and zoom functionality in uiaxes in matlab appdesigner?
appdesigner was introduced in matlab r2016a and officially it doesn't support these options.

Comment: Where are you seeing that it doesn't officially support panning and zooming? Adding [`pan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pan.html) and [`zoom`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html) to a callback functions as expected.

Comment: In matlab documentation.

Comment: Update to R2017a or newer. Or programmatically add an [`axes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) object.

Comment: I think we can not add an axes object programmatically in appdesigner.

Comment: Also i am only interested in adding these features in 2016a. Upgrading isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 5):

For Zooming: `zoom(app.UIAxes1,'on');`

For Pan: `pan(app.UIAxes1,'on');`

Obviously your UIAxes name may not be `app.UIAxes1`.

Answer (score 1):

Good news.
The toolbars are now supported in 2019a.
An example can be found below:

```
[tb,btns] = axtoolbar(app.UIAxes,{'zoomin','zoomout','restoreview'});
```

[image: Example run in Matlab 2019a]

Comment: Upgrading isn't an option for me.